# UICollectionView method deselectItemAtIndexPath doesn't deselect just selected item

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to give to UICollectionView item basically a button behavior, at least partly and not really wanting to ad button as subview, because I want to leverage the standard selection methods of collection view and the protocols involved.

I want to make item a switch button and although the path to do it looks easy, it doesn't actually work.

First I implemented

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and then I called

```
- (void)deselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated
```

from one separate delegate method. THe method seems to be called properly, but item does not change selection property. Actually, when checking "selected" property on the item, from "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" delegate method, I found out the property to be always NO, although background has changed accordingly...

Funny thing is that I can't change the value myself, although this property is not define as read-only....

Has anyone cracked similar nut already? Or we can say this is most probably buggy stuff?

Comment: You should post your code for cellForItemAtIndexPath and didSelectItemAtIndexPath, so we can see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set a _isSelected BOOL in the cell. In the subclass of the cell set to false

Then at selectedCellForRow...

```
[cell applySelection];
```

In subclassed cell:

```
-(void)applySelection{
if(_isSelected){
   _isSelected=false;
   self.setImage (or whatever you want to do, do signify not selected)
}else{
   _isSelected=true;
   //do whatever to signify selection
}
```